# In WPF, why does the Rectangle.Fill property not seem to work when using a TemplateBinding?

Tags: wpf, templatebinding

I can't figure out why this XAML code does not work. When using a TemplateBinding (see below), the background color is **not** set. But when I use a normal color string (i.e. "Red"), it works fine.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="InstanceButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding Background}"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Yet, when I use a TemplateBinding in this way, it works Fine...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="InstanceButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Any ideas?

***Edit:*** to clarify, I intend to expand this to rather use a gradient brush, that's why I need to be able to assign to the Rectangle.Fill property using XAML instead of a plain string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because Color has a different type then Background

Background is a Brush, Color is a.. well Color.. You can use a IValueConverter to convert your brush to a color..

HTH

Comment: That was my thought as well, but then I saw (using intellisense), Background (on Control) is actually a Brush, not a color.

Comment: @willemo, that's exactly it though.  Background is a Brush, and Rectangle.Fill is a brush.  When you set SolidColorBrush.Color to the Background property, it fails because SolidColorBrush.Color is a Color, and Background is a Brush.  Rectangle.Fill=Background is the way to go...both brushes.

Comment: Or write a nasty implementation of an IValueConverter which can convert brushes into colors... You do have to handle all different kind of brushes though.. more info on brushes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx